# Why does CheckPoint not work with Windows 10 ARM64 and Parallels on MacBook M1?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, parallels, arm, checkpoint-endpoint

I installed Parallels and Windows 10 (Insider Preview_Client_ARM64_en-us_21390) on a MacBook Air with an M1 chip. CheckPoint E85.10 does not start in the VM under Windows 10 (error: Connectivity with the VPN service is lost). What could be the problem? Maybe someone has a solution?

Comment: Is the software compatible with Windows for ARM?

Comment: @DanielB - I can also guarantee the answer to that question is it absolutely does not support Windows 10 on ARM